# I am trying to upgrade and Composer is complaining. How do I figure out what the actual issue is and fix it?

Tags: composer, upgrading, 10

I am trying to update my Drupal 9 site to Drupal 10. I installed the *Upgrade status* module (and removed it before trying to update); my site is good with the exception of updating the *Dynamic Entity Reference* module, which requires Drupal 10.

I followed the [Upgrading a Composer-based site](https://www.drupal.org/docs/upgrading-drupal/upgrading-from-drupal-8-or-later/upgrading-a-composer-based-site) documentation but when I try to run `composer update`, I get these errors.

```
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - symfony-cmf/routing[1.4.0, ..., 1.4.1] require php ^5.3.9|^7.0 -> your php version (8.2.9) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - drupal/core[8.9.11, ..., 8.9.20] require php ^7.0.8 -> your php version (8.2.9) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - Root composer.json requires drupal/linkchecker ^1.1 -> satisfiable by drupal/linkchecker[1.1.0].
    - drupal/core-recommended 10.0.2 requires drupal/core 10.0.2 -> satisfiable by drupal/core[10.0.2].
    - Conclusion: don't install drupal/core 10.0.2 (conflict analysis result)
    - drupal/core-recommended 10.0.3 requires drupal/core 10.0.3 -> satisfiable by drupal/core[10.0.3].
    - Conclusion: don't install drupal/core 10.0.3 (conflict analysis result)
    - drupal/core-recommended 10.0.4 requires drupal/core 10.0.4 -> satisfiable by drupal/core[10.0.4].
    - Conclusion: don't install drupal/core 10.0.4 (conflict analysis result)
    - drupal/core-recommended 10.0.5 requires drupal/core 10.0.5 -> satisfiable by drupal/core[10.0.5].
    - Conclusion: don't install drupal/core 10.0.5 (conflict analysis result)
    - drupal/core-recommended 10.0.6 requires drupal/core 10.0.6 -> satisfiable by drupal/core[10.0.6].
    - Conclusion: don't install drupal/core 10.0.6 (conflict analysis result)
    - drupal/core-recommended 10.0.7 requires drupal/core 10.0.7 -> satisfiable by drupal/core[10.0.7].
    - Conclusion: don't install drupal/core 10.0.7 (conflict analysis result)
    - drupal/core-recommended 10.0.8 requires drupal/core 10.0.8 -> satisfiable by drupal/core[10.0.8].
    - Conclusion: don't install drupal/core 10.0.8 (conflict analysis result)
    - drupal/core-recommended 10.0.9 requires drupal/core 10.0.9 -> satisfiable by drupal/core[10.0.9].
    - Conclusion: don't install drupal/core 10.0.9 (conflict analysis result)
    - drupal/core-recommended 10.0.10 requires drupal/core 10.0.10 -> satisfiable by drupal/core[10.0.10].
    - Conclusion: don't install drupal/core 10.0.10 (conflict analysis result)
    - drupal/core-recommended 10.0.11 requires drupal/core 10.0.11 -> satisfiable by drupal/core[10.0.11].
    - Conclusion: don't install drupal/core 10.0.11 (conflict analysis result)
    - drupal/core-recommended 10.1.0 requires drupal/core 10.1.0 -> satisfiable by drupal/core[10.1.0].
    - Conclusion: don't install drupal/core 10.1.0 (conflict analysis result)
    - drupal/core-recommended 10.1.1 requires drupal/core 10.1.1 -> satisfiable by drupal/core[10.1.1].
    - Conclusion: don't install drupal/core 10.1.1 (conflict analysis result)
    - drupal/core-recommended 10.1.2 requires drupal/core 10.1.2 -> satisfiable by drupal/core[10.1.2].
    - Conclusion: don't install drupal/core 10.1.2 (conflict analysis result)
    - drupal/core-recommended 10.1.3 requires drupal/core 10.1.3 -> satisfiable by drupal/core[10.1.3].
    - Conclusion: don't install drupal/core 10.1.3 (conflict analysis result)
    - drupal/core-recommended 10.1.4 requires drupal/core 10.1.4 -> satisfiable by drupal/core[10.1.4].
    - Conclusion: don't install drupal/core 10.1.4 (conflict analysis result)
    - drupal/core-recommended 10.1.5 requires drupal/core 10.1.5 -> satisfiable by drupal/core[10.1.5].
    - Conclusion: don't install drupal/core 10.1.5 (conflict analysis result)
    - drupal/core-recommended 10.1.6 requires drupal/core 10.1.6 -> satisfiable by drupal/core[10.1.6].
    - Conclusion: don't install drupal/core 10.1.6 (conflict analysis result)
    - drupal/core[8.9.0, ..., 8.9.10] require symfony-cmf/routing ^1.4 -> satisfiable by symfony-cmf/routing[1.4.0, 1.4.1].
    - drupal/core-recommended 10.0.1 requires drupal/core 10.0.1 -> satisfiable by drupal/core[10.0.1].
    - Conclusion: don't install drupal/core 10.0.1 (conflict analysis result)
    - drupal/linkchecker 1.1.0 requires drupal/core ^8.9 || ^9.2 -> satisfiable by drupal/core[8.9.0, ..., 8.9.20, 9.2.0, ..., 9.5.11].
    - You can only install one version of a package, so only one of these can be installed: drupal/core[8.0.0, ..., 8.9.20, 9.0.0, ..., 9.5.11, 10.0.0, ..., 10.1.6].
    - You can only install one version of a package, so only one of these can be installed: drupal/core[8.7.0, ..., 8.9.20, 9.0.0, ..., 9.5.11, 10.0.0, ..., 10.1.6].
    - drupal/core-recommended 10.0.0 requires drupal/core 10.0.0 -> satisfiable by drupal/core[10.0.0].
    - Root composer.json requires drupal/core-recommended ^10 -> satisfiable by drupal/core-recommended[10.0.0, ..., 10.1.6].
```

I tried specifically updating symfony-cmf/routing to the 2.x version, but that still threw errors.
I really struggle digging through the lines of problems to figure out what the actual issue is.

Does anybody know how I can fix this and explain how you figured that out, so that I can hopefully know for the future?

Comment: Sometimes when you have a single module to update (Dynamic Entity Reference), composer can get stuck.  Assuming you are using version control for your site, delete `composer.lock` and the `vendor` directories, and then run `composer clear-cache`.  This will wipe out all your locally installed package info.  Then try running `composer update` to generate a fresh `composer.lock`.

Comment: drupal/linkchecker 1.1.0 requires drupal/core ^8.9 || ^9.2

Comment: To figure out why, you can run `composer prohibits drupal/core 10.1.6`

Comment: @cilefen, the question is why it didn't show in the upgrade status module. Eluchel, can you reinstall the upgrade status module and check if everything is green?

Comment: Does upgrade status scan disabled modules?

Comment: Yes, and it tells you to remove it because you don't use it anyway.

Comment: Is the version of PHP outdated as well?

Comment: @Kevin no php was just updated to 8.2+

Answer (score 0):

> I am trying to update my Drupal 9 site to Drupal 10. I installed the
> Upgrade Status module (and removed it before trying to update)

This is great, this should prevent any composer errors. Reinstall the *Upgrade Status* module to look again. Is there an entry for the *Link Checker* module? It should be in the *Update* section, or if not installed by Drupal in the *Remove* section with the description:

> The likely best action is to remove projects that are uninstalled. Why
> invest in updating them to be compatible if you are not using them?